# For some reason my input values will not show and my Chr(149) will not output correctly

Tags: vb.net

I have this procedure and I cannot get it to output my input numbers as well as the correct number of dots to go along with the corresponding grade.

Example for output should be:
High Grade ********* 94
Low Grade ******* 75
Range ** 19
Average ******** 85

with the "*" representing the dots being the grade divided by 10

But for some reason I am getting ** 0.00 for all of my values.

```
Private Sub btnStats_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStats.Click
    If DataOk() Then
        Dim max, min, sum As Double
        Dim dots As String = ""


        lstOutput.Items.Clear()
        lstOutput.Items.Add("Student Letter Grade Summary")
        lstOutput.Items.Add("Course - " & txtCourse.Text)
        lstOutput.Items.Add("Semester - " & txtSemester.Text)
        DisplaySummary(dots, max, min, sum)
        ProcessSummary(max, min, sum)

    End If

End Sub
Sub ProcessSummary(ByRef max As Double, ByRef min As Double, ByRef sum As Double)
    Dim grade As Integer

    min = 0
    max = 100
    For i As Integer = 0 To lstGrade.Items.Count - 1
        grade = CInt(lstGrade.Items(i))
        If grade > min Then
            min = grade
        End If
        If grade < max Then
            max = grade
        End If
        sum += grade
    Next
End Sub
Sub DisplaySummary(ByRef dots As String, ByRef max As Double, ByRef min As Double, ByRef range As Double)
    lstOutput.Items.Clear()
    lstOutput.Items.Add("High grade " & " " & LineOfDots(CType(max / 10, String)) & max.ToString("n2"))
    lstOutput.Items.Add("Low grade " & " " & LineOfDots(CType(min / 10, String)) & min.ToString("n2"))
    lstOutput.Items.Add("Range " & " " & LineOfDots(CType(max - min / 10, String)) & (max - min).ToString("n2"))
    lstOutput.Items.Add("Average " & " " & LineOfDots(CType(max + min / 10, String)) & ((max + min) / 2).ToString("n2"))

End Sub
Function LineOfDots(ByVal dots As String) As String
    For i As Integer = 1 To lstGrade.Items.Count - 1
        LineOfDots &= Chr(149)
    Next

    Return LineOfDots
End Function
```

Comment: Hmm...would it possibly make a difference if you called `ProcessSummary()` before `DisplaySummary()`?...

Comment: *facepalm* Okay that fixed the issue about the grades not showing up but the correct number of dots is not showing up.  It's always better to have two sets of eyes. Thank you for that though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `LineOfDots()` to receive an *Integer* and use the [String Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
Function LineOfDots(ByVal dots As Integer) As String
    Return New String(Chr(149), dots)
End Function
```

Then here would be a new example of how to call it:

```
lstOutput.Items.Add("High grade " & LineOfDots(max / 10) & " " & max.ToString("n2"))
```

Comment: ok thank you that got everything working smoothly, except for the range and the average. It outputs what seems to be and infinite amount of dots

Comment: fixed it. Thank you so much!